# How can I cache a TensorFlow dataset for a specific number of epochs and then re-generate the dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

currently I have a TensorFlow Dataset defined as:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: sample_generator(
        vocab_name, model_name, n_synonyms=5, use_closest_words=True
    ),
    output_signature=(
        (
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32),
        ),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, None), dtype=tf.float64),
    ),
)
```

Since computing the dataset is quite expensive, I then train my model using:

```
model.fit(
    x=dataset.batch(cfg.tf_parms.batch_size).prefetch(12).cache(),
    callbacks=[cp_callback],
    epochs=600
)
```

This results in optimal training speed for my model at around 4ms/epoch.

However I would now like to re-compute the dataset every X epochs - but I cannot find how to do it in an efficient way. Ideally, the dataset would be cached for X epochs, then recomputed, then the new dataset would be cached, etc.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by looping your calls to fit.

```
for epoch in range(600//X):
  model.fit(
      x=dataset.batch(cfg.tf_parms.batch_size).prefetch(12).cache(),
      callbacks=[cp_callback],
      epochs=epoch + X,
      initial_epoch=epoch
  )  
  reset_ds()
```

But that doesn't always handle callbacks the way you'd expect. Another way to would be to do it outside of TF and inside the generator - just have it doing the caching itself, and you can control the replacement policy (e.g. 25% chance of generating a new datapoint, 75% using a cached one).